# TextWatcher warnings and slow type in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I want to change on type a character in android. If user type `space` or `-` it will change it to `_`

So I tried:

```
TextWatcher tt = null;

final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
   tt = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            etUsername.setSelection(s.length());
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            etUsername.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
            etUsername.setText(etUsername.getText().toString().replace(" ", "_"));
            etUsername.setText(etUsername.getText().toString().replace("-", "_"));
            etUsername.addTextChangedListener(tt);
        }
    };
    etUsername.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

it "works" but if user types fast some letters will not appear and I got some warnings:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: commitText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: commitText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: commitText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: commitText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remove and add text change listener again and again on text change, just put a condition to check if your editable is having "-" or " " then just replace and set it to EditText.

```
etUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0 && (s.toString().contains("-") || s.toString().contains(" "))) {
                    etUsername.setText(s.toString().replace("-", "_").replace(" ", "_"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                etUsername.setSelection(s.length());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Textwatcher

```
  TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        output.setText(s);
        if(a == 9){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }};
```

Comment: more guide available in android developer - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)